# displaying hour, minutes and seconds in two digits in Timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I am using javascript to show total time elapsed on my website with following code.

It is working correctly....but the problem is when seconds = 0, it's field is empty and when seconds and minutes are between 1 to 9, it is showing one digit.Instead I want to show as follows

```
if 59 seconds then == 00:00:59 (curretnly showing 59)
if 62 seconds then == 00:01:02 (currently showing 1:2)
if 70 seconds then == 00:01:10 (currently showing 1:10)
if 3640 seconds then == 01:00:40 (currently showing 1:0:40)
```

I mean fields shown should be fixed with

> 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)

format

javascript code using as follows :

```
var timeStamp = Date.now(),
sessionStamp = sessionStorage.getItem('ts'),
elapsedTime;
  if (!sessionStamp) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('ts', timeStamp.toString());
    sessionStamp = timeStamp;
  } else {
    sessionStamp = parseInt(sessionStamp);
  }

function increment() {
    elapsedTime = Date.now() - sessionStamp;
    d1= Math.round(elapsedTime / 1000).toString();
    d = Number(d1);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? ":" : ":") : "";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? ":" : ":") : "";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? "0" : "") : "";

    document.getElementById('elapsedTime').textContent = hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
 }
    setInterval(increment, 1000);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zf3poxwg/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/03L9pcm2/

Here is what I have changed

```
var hDisplay = h > 0 ? (h < 10 ? "0" + h + ":" : h + ":") : "00:";
var mDisplay = m > 0 ? (m < 10 ? "0" + m + ":" : m + ":") : "00:";
var sDisplay = s > 0 ? (s < 10 ? "0" + s : s) : "00";
```

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to format the hours, minutes and seconds slightly differently.

I forked your example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/samrae/xb6n5Lda/6/

```
var timeStamp = Date.now(),
sessionStamp = sessionStorage.getItem('ts'),
elapsedTime;
if (!sessionStamp) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('ts', timeStamp.toString());
  sessionStamp = timeStamp;
}
else {
  sessionStamp = parseInt(sessionStamp);
}

function increment() {
  elapsedTime = Date.now() - sessionStamp;
  d1= Math.round(elapsedTime / 1000).toString();
  d = Number(d1);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? (h < 10 ? "0" : "") + h + ":" : "00:";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? (m < 10 ? "0" : "") + m + ":" : "00:";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s : "00";


    document.getElementById('elapsedTime').textContent = hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}
setInterval(increment, 1000);
```

You're on the right track with checking if the seconds are bigger than 0 but you were printing an empty string if they are as apposed to what you need which is "00".

You could separate out the logic for making the hours, mins and seconds into separate functions so that it's easier to follow

Comment: worked perfectly as i needed... but I am sorry, as cdoshi posted answer  earlier and I tried it and worked and I marked it as accepted answer....and then I saw your answer.....sorry once again and thanks for kind help

Comment: No problem. Glad you got an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is my own trick. **simple** and **short** and **stylish**:

```
var hDisplay = (h < 0 ? "00" : ("0"+h).slice(-2)) + ":";
//And others ...
```